# PureScript Halogen and websockets

Tags: websocket, purescript, halogen

I'm trying to use `purescript-halogen` in combination with websockets, but after several attempts I'm unable to make them work together.

I've seen [this question on Thermite and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287369/purescript-thermite-and-websockets) and Phil's answer regarding the `Driver` function. Halogen also has a `Driver` function, but I need to run the `Driver` function with the `Aff` effect, while `purescript-websockets-simple` uses the `Eff` effect.

I've no idea how to transform the synchronous callbacks of the websocket package to asynchronous code running in the `Aff` monad. Do I need to use an `AVar`? Do I need `purescript-coroutines-aff`? If so, how do I hook up these parts together?

Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case you would indeed want to use `purescript-aff-coroutines`. That will get you a coroutine `Producer` that you can then hook up to a `Consumer` that pushes messages into the driver:

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Control.Coroutine (Producer, Consumer, consumer, runProcess, ($$))
import Control.Coroutine.Aff (produce)
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff)
import Control.Monad.Aff.AVar (AVAR)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Var (($=))

import Data.Array as Array
import Data.Either (Either(..))
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))

import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML.Indexed as HH
import Halogen.Util (runHalogenAff, awaitBody)

import WebSocket (WEBSOCKET, Connection(..), Message(..), URL(..), runMessageEvent, runMessage, newWebSocket)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Halogen component. This just displays a list of messages and has a query
-- to accept new messages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type State = { messages :: Array String }

initialState :: State
initialState = { messages: [] }

data Query a = AddMessage String a

ui :: forall g. H.Component State Query g
ui = H.component { render, eval }
  where
  render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
  render state =
    HH.ol_ $ map (\msg -> HH.li_ [ HH.text msg ]) state.messages

  eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query g
  eval (AddMessage msg next) = do
    H.modify \st -> { messages: st.messages `Array.snoc` msg }
    pure next

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Websocket coroutine producer. This uses `purescript-aff-coroutines` to
-- create a producer of messages from a websocket.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

wsProducer :: forall eff. Producer String (Aff (avar :: AVAR, err :: EXCEPTION, ws :: WEBSOCKET | eff)) Unit
wsProducer = produce \emit -> do
  Connection socket <- newWebSocket (URL "ws://echo.websocket.org") []

  -- This part is probably unnecessary in the real world, but it gives us 
  -- some messages to consume when using the echo service
  socket.onopen $= \event -> do
    socket.send (Message "hello")
    socket.send (Message "something")
    socket.send (Message "goodbye")

  socket.onmessage $= \event -> do
    emit $ Left $ runMessage (runMessageEvent event)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Coroutine consumer. This accepts a Halogen driver function and sends
-- `AddMessage` queries in when the coroutine consumes an input.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

wsConsumer
  :: forall eff
   . (Query ~> Aff (H.HalogenEffects (ws :: WEBSOCKET | eff)))
  -> Consumer String (Aff (H.HalogenEffects (ws :: WEBSOCKET | eff))) Unit
wsConsumer driver = consumer \msg -> do
  driver $ H.action $ AddMessage msg
  pure Nothing

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Normal Halogen-style `main`, the only addition is a use of `runProcess`
-- to connect the producer and consumer and start sending messages to the
-- Halogen component.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

main :: forall eff. Eff (H.HalogenEffects (ws :: WEBSOCKET | eff)) Unit
main = runHalogenAff do
  body <- awaitBody
  driver <- H.runUI ui initialState body
  runProcess (wsProducer $$ wsConsumer driver)
  pure unit
```

This should give you a page that almost immediately prints:

1. hello
2. something
3. goodbye

But it is doing everything you need, honest! If you use the producer with a "real" source you'll get something more like what you need.